# ROS Answers SE migration: run the rviz

Tags: ros, rviz, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Each time I run the rviz  "rosrun rviz rviz" I have to "export LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1".
And if I open a new windows, I have to export it again.
I want to know how should I do if just set it once,and next time I run rviz,I can not set it.
Thank you very much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/230775/run-the-rviz/) by [littlestar](https://answers.ros.org/users/26326/littlestar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2016-04-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want an environment variable (like LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE) to be set automatically every time you open a new terminal, add it to the bash startup file (`.bashrc`) in your home directory.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [littlestar](https://answers.ros.org/users/26326/littlestar/) on 2016-04-02**:
Thank you!